# How to disable the OptionParser default help view?

Tags: python

I am using the OptionParser from optparse module to parse my command that I get using the raw_input(). When I give a -h it displays the help screen and exits my application. I dont want it to display the help screen or exit the application. How can this be accomplished?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Proper stackoverflow etiquette says you should accept an answer when one is correct, and not add follow-on questions to your original question.  Create a new question instead.

Comment: I am just a n00b and I will do it next time. Please help me with this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

optparse has a strange penchange for exiting your program, which I think is really unfortunate.  You can initialize it like this to prevent it:

```
oparser = OptionParser(add_help_option=False, ...)
```

Note that now you have to handle the `-h` and `--help` options yourself.  You can print the help message formatted by OptionParser like this:

```
print(oparser.format_help().strip())
```

Comment: if add_help_option=False then can I assign -h to something else?

Comment: Yes, once you turn off OptParser's help stuff, then you can do whatever you want with `-h` and `--help`.

Answer (score 7):

set [`add_help_option`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#creating-the-parser) to False

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser(add_help_option=False)
parser.add_option('-h', '--help', help='show this help message')
options, args = parser.parse_args()
if options.help:
   parser.print_help()
```

> `add_help_option (default: True)`
>
> If true, optparse will add a help option
>   (with option strings "-h" and
>   "--help") to the parser.

Comment: thanx but, what if i dont want it to exit my application?